# Access python objects from bottle webserver

Tags: python, bottle

maybe a stupid question, but I can't think of a logical pythonic way to solve my problem.

I have a application controlling some relays on a Raspberry Pi which I want to write a simple web interface for. I chose bottle for that.
Right now I have created a `RelayController` class which gets instantiated in a `main.py` file and takes care of initializing the hardware and switching the relays when I press the buttons. It also gets some configuration passed and everything works as expected.

Now I want a web interface that can display the state of the relays and add some buttons which will have the same function as the physical buttons.
My plan for creating the interface was to query a dict from the `RelayController` class and then render a template accordingly. That's the point where I'm stuck.
I can start the webserver in my `main.py` file with `bottle.run()`, but since the web app lives in another file I can't pass the `RelayController` instance to it and since the `RelayController` is created during runtime, I can't import it.

Is there any easy way to do that, am I missing something really simple?
Also this will be an application that isn't used publicly or even by multiple users so I strive for a simple solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It isn't clear how you are doing the "render a tempalte accordingly" step.  I am guessing from your wording that you are making a "thick client" in you main.py that is rendering directly to a window.  If that is the case, then you need an endpoint on your bottle server that sends you the dictionary from the RelayController, that you get with a get request to that server.  The alternative is to render the "template" in html to your browser from an endpoint on your bottle server.

Comment: Move RelayController and associated logic out of main.py into a new module which can be imported from main.py, your bottle code, or anywhere else.

Comment: I want to use botte to serve an rendered htmł template containing the info presented to the user. So bottle needs a way to query a dict or some other data structure from `RelayController`